# Unable to create Dynamic Web project in eclipse when php plugins are installed

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created some dynamic web projects and they are working fine.
After that I have installed PHP development plugins in eclipse. 
Also installed xdebug plugin for PHP debugging.

Now When I create Java Dynamic Web Project I get this error:

```
The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in "org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui" was unable to instantiate class 
"org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.project.facet.WebProjectWizard".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**EDIT**: I have WTP installed.

I am able to create java static web project and PHP projects. But not able to create Java Dynamic web project.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hmm maybe the additional PHP plugin is causing WebProjectWizard to load the wrong class. If all else fails what you can do is have separate installation of eclipse, one for java and the other for php

Comment: First thought the same thing when searched for this error in stackoverflow. But thought if it is possible to have them both, then why can't So asked this question.

Comment: What version of WTP do you have installed?  Can you post the full error log/ stacktrace?

Comment: @gamerson: I have installed Version: 3.2.0.v201004210642-377A78s73533B7L3935. Log has so much data.

Comment: Can you delete the contents of your log and then replicate the error again and then the log should only contain a single stack trace.

Comment: any solution for this problem , I got the same error with Eclipse . I m using Spring and Web logic

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem so I did this :

1. Go to window
2. Perspective -> open perspective
3. click on other
4. Then Java EE

Now open Dynamic Web Page it will open
If this doesn't work you make reinstall new software here's how :

1. Click on Help and then click on “Install New Software”.
2. Paste this link: Mars- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars in work with field
3. Find Web, XML, Java EE and OSGI Enterprise Development and expand it.
4. Select these options :

Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools ,
Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools ,
Eclipse Web Developer Tools,

5. Click next until software is installed then restart eclipse.

Answer (score -2):

it happened to me the same ... solution: create another workspace and go!

Comment: This answer is rather short, but it might work for new projects. Unfortunately it does not explain what to do with the already existing projects.